# Decode String with swift 3

Tags: ios, json, swift, web-services, utf-8

I got the following encoded string in my web service response

```
  \U00e0\U00aa\U0095\U00e0\U00ab\U0083\U00e0\U00aa\U00aa\U00e0\U00aa\U00be \U00e0\U00aa\U0095\U00e0\U00aa\U00b0\U00e0\U00ab\U0080\U00e0\U00aa\U00a8\U00e0\U00ab\U0087 \U00e0\U00aa\U009f\U00e0\U00ab\U008b\U00e0\U00aa\U00a1 \U00e0\U00aa\U008f\U00e0\U00aa\U00aa\U00e0\U00ab\U008d\U00e0\U00aa\U00b2\U00e0\U00aa\U00bf\U00e0\U00aa\U0095\U00e0\U00ab\U0087\U00e0\U00aa\U00b6\U00e0\U00aa\U00a8 \U00e0\U00aa\U00a4\U00e0\U00aa\U00aa\U00e0\U00aa\U00be\U00e0\U00aa\U00b8\U00e0\U00ab\U008b. \U00e0\U00aa\U00a4\U00e0\U00ab\U008d\U00e0\U00aa\U00af\U00e0\U00aa\U00be\U00e0\U00aa\U0082 \U00e0\U00aa\U00aa\U00e0\U00ab\U008d\U00e0\U00aa\U00b0\U00e0\U00aa\U00b5\U00e0\U00aa\U00be\U00e0\U00aa\U00b8 \U00e0\U00aa\U00ae\U00e0\U00aa\U00be\U00e0\U00aa\U009f\U00e0\U00ab\U0087 \U00e0\U00aa\U008f\U00e0\U00aa\U0095 \U00e0\U00aa\U00a8\U00e0\U00aa\U00b5\U00e0\U00ab\U0080 \U00e0\U00aa\U00a4\U00e0\U00aa\U00aa\U00e0\U00aa\U00be\U00e0\U00aa\U00b8 \U00e0\U00aa\U009b\U00e0\U00ab\U0087
```

and also

```
àªà«àªªàª¾ àªàª°à«àª¨à« àªà«àª¡ àªàªªà«àªàªªà«àª\302²àª¿àªàªªà«àª\302²àª¿àª\303à«àª¶àª¨ àª¤àªªàª¾ààªªà«àª\302²àª¿àª\303à«àª¶àª¨ àª¤àªªàª¾à\302ª¸à«. àª¤à«àª¯àª¾àª àªªà«àª°àªµàª¾àª¸ àª®àª¾àªà« àªàª àª¨àªµà« àª¤àªªàª¾àª¸ àªà«.
```

so how can i decode both the string in swift 3.

got following object in json(Postman Output)

```
 {

  "message": "કૃપા કરીને એપ્લિકેશન તપાસો. ત્યાં પ્રવાસ માટે એક નવી તપાસ છે.",

},
{

  "message": "કૃપા કરીને એપ્લિકેશન તપાસો. ત્યાં પ્રવાસ માટે એક નવી તપાસ છે.",

}
```

but in xcode i got following

```
"Notifications" : [
{

  "message" : "àªà«àªªàª¾ àªàª°à«àª¨à« àªà«àª¡ àªàªªà«àªàªªà«àª\302²àª¿àªàªªà«àª\302²àª¿àª\303à«àª¶àª¨ àª¤àªªàª¾ààªªà«àª\302²àª¿àª\303à«àª¶àª¨ àª¤àªªàª¾à\302ª¸à«. àª¤à«àª¯àª¾àª àªªà«àª°àªµàª¾àª¸ àª®àª¾àªà« àªàª àª¨àªµà« àª¤àªªàª¾àª¸ àªà«.",

},
{

  "message" : "àªà«àªªàª¾ àªàª°à«àª¨à« àªà«àª¡ àªàªªà«àª²àª¿àªà«àª¶àª¨ àª¤àªªàª¾àª¸à«. àª¤à«àª¯àª¾àª àªªà«àª°àªµàª¾àª¸ àª®àª¾àªà« àªàª àª¨àªµà« àª¤àªªàª¾àª¸ àªà«.",

}
```

Comment: please check updated que.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're just printing the nested `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` objects, which does not properly render the UTF8 strings:

```
let originalJsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)

print("\(originalJsonObject)")                    // this will show the cryptic \U00ee\U00a0 ... result
```

That will show text much like you shared in your question:

> ...
>           message = "\U0a95\U0ac3\U0aaa\U0abe \U0a95\U0ab0\U0ac0\U0aa8\U0ac7 \U0a9f\U0acb\U0aa1 \U0a8f\U0aaa\U0acd\U0ab2\U0abf\U0a95\U0ac7\U0ab6\U0aa8 \U0aa4\U0aaa\U0abe\U0ab8\U0acb. \U0aa4\U0acd\U0aaf\U0abe\U0a82 \U0aaa\U0acd\U0ab0\U0ab5\U0abe\U0ab8 \U0aae\U0abe\U0a9f\U0ac7 \U0a8f\U0a95 \U0aa8\U0ab5\U0ac0 \U0aa4\U0aaa\U0abe\U0ab8 \U0a9b\U0ac7.";
>   ...

But if you go ahead and use that object, you'll see that everything is actually OK:

```
guard
    let json = originalJsonObject as? [String: Any],
    let notifications = json["Notifications"] as? [[String: Any]],
    let string = notifications[0]["message"] as? String else {
        print("problem parsing")
        return
}
print("\(string)")
```

That will show:

> કૃપા કરીને ટોડ એપ્લિકેશન તપાસો. ત્યાં પ્રવાસ માટે એક નવી તપાસ છે.

Clearly, the details of how you extract the string will be a function of the broader JSON structure, what API you used to parse it, etc., but it illustrates the idea. Don't worry about how the `NSDictionary` is displayed, but go ahead and get the `String` object, and you'll see that the UTF8 string can be used just fine.